# /snap/bin/microk8s error - permanently dropping privs did not work: File exists

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, microk8s

Has anyone come across this issue before?

```
/snap/bin/microk8s
permanently dropping privs did not work: File exists
```

I get the same error when trying to run any of the other sub commands like microk8s.enable, microk8s.status, microk8s.kubectl - all same error message.

I tried to:

- run `strace` with the command to see if I can figure out what "File exists" - Nothing fruitful came of that.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Experiencing this too, looks like it's coming from snap: https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/9925476121cdd1c19e3e479c6bac6c5bed045bf8/cmd/snap-confine/snap-confine.c#L523-L526

Answer (score 4):

I had a same error message when I execute docker command after installing docker via snap.
After logout-login, the error was solved in my case.

Comment: It works with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, thank you. `exit` , `sudo -i` , `docker version`

Answer (score 3):

I asked this on the #microk8s channel on the Kubernetes Slack and someone informed me that running `sudo microk8s` would fix this issue. It works with that for me.